# Binascii.unhexlify typeerror Odd length string

Tags: python, regex, hex

I have written following script to get rid of non-alphanumeric characters, and get them back afterwards. However I can't seem to figure out why the `unhexlify` will not work. Any suggestions?

```
import binascii, timeit, re

damn_string = "asjke5234nlkfs$sfj3.$sfjk."

def convert_string(s):
    return ''.join('__UTF%s__' % binascii.hexlify(c.encode('utf-16')) if not c.isalnum() else c for c in s.lower())

def convert_back(s):
    for i in re.findall('__UTF([a-f0-9]{8})__', s): # For testing
        print binascii.unhexlify(i).decode('utf-16')
    return re.sub('__UTF([a-f0-9]{8})__', binascii.unhexlify('\g<1>').decode('utf-16'), s)

convert = convert_string(damn_string)
print convert
print convert_back(convert)
```

result in the following output:

```
asjke5234nlkfs__UTFfffe2400__sfj3__UTFfffe2e00____UTFfffe2400__sfjk__UTFfffe2e00__
$
.
$
.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 131, in <module>
    print convert_back(convert)
  File "test.py", line 127, in convert_back
    return re.sub('__UTF([a-f0-9]{8})__', binascii.unhexlify('\g<1>').decode('utf-16'), s)
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I took me a bit too long to realize that re.sub cannot submit the group string in this manner. One way of doing this is:

```
return re.sub('__UTF([a-f0-9]{8})__', lambda x: binascii.unhexlify(x.group(1)).decode('utf-16'), s)
```